# Php inside javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

What i am trying to do is inside script tags run javascript inside the php loops. 
For example:

```
<script>
$('#mydiv').mouseover(function(){
time();
function time(){
<?php  
    $secs = 45; 
    $secs--;
if($secs <= 25){
?>//javascript code here 
}
});
</script>
```

My main purpose is when the user mouseover a div, a javascript function runs and inside that javascript function there is php if conitions. If the time is less then 25 then do a specified javascript code. then another condition if the time is less that 10 then do another javascript function.Any type of help will be appreciated. THanks

Comment: You have serious misconceptions about what PHP and Javascript are. They cannot work together directly - PHP runs on the server, and javascript on the client.

Comment: And even if it would work, you do realise that the only thing that happens in the PHP function is `$secs` becomes 44, and will therefore never be smaller than 25?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript is client-side script, PHP is server-side script. So, either you do [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls to server or just pure JS.

**AJAX+PHP:**

```
<script>
    $('#mydiv').mouseover(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'secs.php',
            success: function(data) {
                var secs = parseInt(data);

                if(secs <= 10) {
                    // do stuff
                }
                else if(secs <= 25) {
                    // do stuff
                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

secs.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['secs'])) $_SESSION['secs'] = 45;
    else echo $_SESSION['secs'] --;
?>
```

**Pure JS:**

```
<script>
    var secs = 45;

    $('#mydiv').mouseover(function(){
        secs --;

        if(secs <= 10) {
            // do stuff
        }
        else if (secs <= 25) {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I know about how to do with js. Anyway thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 3):

PHP runs on the server and outputs some text.

The browser then interprets that text as HTML/JS/etc.

You can't run PHP in response to a client side event unless you issue a new HTTP request.

If you know the values that your PHP cares about at the time of page build, then you can generate JavaScript with that data stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PHP within Javascript, if you need server side operations you should use AJAX. [jQuery has a neat implementation of it.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this because php run on server and javascript on client.
It means that your php code is transformed into DHTML on server and send to client.
But javascript runs on client... So if you want to combine both of them. you have to request server from client again (by ajax for example).

But back to your code... why do you don't count time in javascript?
you can get what you want by `var date = new Date(); time = date.getCurrentTime()`