# How to call external javascript function inside a php tag?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a php tag and inside that i have a script tag like this ..

```
<?php
   echo' <script language= javascript type= text/javascript>

          //HERE

     </script>';
?>
```

I need to call external javascript function(External means external  .js file)
and this is a .php page and have not 
I know this is a stupid question but plz give me a solution??

> 

No No i edited my question i need to call external js function in side  tags.is there a method to create object from external js file class and call it functions through that object???

Comment: php is server side. JS is _generally_ client side. they don't get mix up. _ajax_ is the way. possible [**duplicate**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079735/php-inside-javascript-function?rq=1)

Comment: you would need to echo the whole block out or close your php tag before the script tags and then reopen after

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Just output the tag and the JS code will be executed on the client-side (!) after the page has been loaded.

```
<?php
     //Some php code
?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     //HERE
  </script>
<?php 
  //Some more code
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this, but don't confuse server side and client side. If you are looking to execute a js script in a php block (before user sees page) you can't you have to use ajax/do it when page has been loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

If trying something like:

```
<script>
$phpvar = myjsfunction();
</script>
somephpfunction($phpvar);#$phpvar is most likely undefined in php script
```

It will create a js variable named `$phpvar` assigned to what `myjsfunction` returned. Otherwise create a ajax call and do what you wanted to do with php but with js.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/file.js">
     </script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  echo '<script>callJavaScriptFunction()</script>'; ?>
```

But the best way is ajax. Do it through ajax.

If you need to write js code or making external class object, then end your PHP tag, and write all your JS code.

Comment: No No i edited my question i need to call external js function in side <script></script> tags.is there a method to create object from external js file class and call it functions through that object???

Answer (score 0):

It is same as you add javascript functions

`<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='JS FILE PATH'></script>"; ?>`

Answer (score -2):

You can't mix JavaScript with PHP like that. Your code above is in general wrong: You should end up with something like that:

```
<?php 
     echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">';
     echo 'myFunction();';
     echo '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: or better.... just remove that dammn `php` tag which has no value here above.

Comment: The OP probably has much complex php page. Removing the tags doesn't help. It makes the code even worst, because it mixes the open and close php tags.

Comment: what `complex` php has to got to do with _javascript_?

Comment: I meant that if you have a big php file it is a little bit messy to open and close php tag.

Comment: not messier than putting javascript, css, hrml, php all in one file only because you wanted to avoid opening/closing brcakets.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but if you have to do it, better keep everything looks like PHP.

Answer (score -3):

Use the following;

```
<?php
   echo" <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
   //PUT YOUR CODE HERE.
   </script>";
?>
```

That will then echo the javascript to the page, and the page will execute the javascript code.  then resume to continue the rest of the PHP Script.